# Manually created vertex group affects area that should not be affected

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones

I manually grouped all vertexes to bones and all of them act properly except for the "shin-L" one
[image: properly working bone]

Exact same bone on other side acts properly:
[image: properly working bone]

Weight paint mode did't give me any more information on problem -

[image: weight paint mode]

I have no idea what is reason of the problem, so any help is appreciated

Link to model - [model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xVEdU7xvLuPy2FuwqSWfJ49vGws7TLHm/view?usp=sharing), all credits to Hakita, i downloaded this model from [here](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/v1-ultrakill-d951a08a8f50412d84e262bad887b285)

I'm just learning how to rig models, so i likely missed something.

Comment: Instead, try to *Parent >> Armature with Automatic Weights*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending vertex is assigned to both hip and foot bones.  Since the foot bone is a child of the shin bone, it deforms with rotation of shin as well as rotation of foot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your model has over 3000 duplicate vertices on it which could be what's causing your problem. In <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode select <kbd>A</kbd>ll then hit <kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>Merge by Distance</kbd> and see if that cures your problem.

[image]

Comment: still have exact same problem, however thanks for the tip on how to clean the model, now i uploaded model without duplicate vertices.